# Validating YAML data in initializers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, yaml

I have a bunch of zip codes stored in multiple arrays in a YAML file. I was planning on reading all this data in an initializer, but wanted to run a validation to make sure each zip code was only in one array. What's the best way to validate that? Here's possible solutions I've come up with:

1. In the initializer, run a validation. If it doesn't pass either throw an error (and prevent startup, which seems drastic), or send it to the logger (and risk not noticing if it's wrong).
2. On deploy, run a validation. Add a capistrano task that checks, and throws an error on deploy.

Any other suggestions or preferences for which one is better?

Comment: Why not store it in the DB as it has built in mechanisms for uniqueness and querying?

Comment: @max Mainly because we didn't want to have to hit the database for relatively static data, and it was easier to just implement everything as a flat file instead of building out the ActiveRecord model for it.

Comment: If the YAML file is stored in your code repository you might want to use a post commit hook. Although I would probably reconsider and use the database together with memcached or redis for caching instead of reinventing the database.